# Is there anything like HTTP::Recorder for Python?

Tags: python, http, proxy, record

I really like Perl's [HTTP::Recorder](http://search.cpan.org/~leira/HTTP-Recorder-0.05/). Is there something like it for Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm aware of Scotch and FunkLoad, but I don't know how they compare with HTTP::Recorder.  See the following links for more details:

- http://darcs.idyll.org/~t/projects/scotch/doc/

  - also see the subsection "Other Python Recorders and Proxies"
- http://funkload.nuxeo.org/#test-recorder

Comment: That's a nice collection. Thanks!